# How to pass a function to a react native custom component but not run until onPress

Tags: react-native, components

I am new to RN.  WRiting my first app. I read the docs on passing functions but am unclear on how to solve my issue.  I have built myself a custom button component.

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native'
import { Theme } from '../Styles/Theme';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'


export const CButton = ({text, icon = null, iconSide = null, onPress}) => {
return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} >
        <View style={Theme.primaryButton}>
            {iconSide == "left" && icon &&
                <AntDesign style={Theme.primaryButtonIcon} name={icon} size={24} color="white" />
            }
            <Text style={Theme.primaryButtonText}>{text}</Text>

            {iconSide == "right" && icon &&
                <AntDesign style={Theme.primaryButtonIcon} name={icon} size={24} color="white" />
            }
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
)
}
```

I think this is pretty basic stuff.

I am using the button as a login button in this case:

```
 <CButton
                text="Login"
                icon="right"
                iconSide="right"
                onPress={login(email, password)}
            />
```

I am passing login(email, password) to the onPress prop and then using it in my custom component like:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress} >
```

The issue is that as the way I am doing this is calling the function on load (I know thats a web term).  Its not waiting until I press the button.

How do I make sure the onPress only happens when the button is pressed?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your way, you are directly calling the login function when component is rendering.

You just need to modify your use of component like this

```
<CButton
     text="Login"
     icon="right"
     iconSide="right"
     onPress={()=> login(email, password)}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This was it.